# Automatic detection of equivalent or replacement items in shopping baskets

Tags: correlation, similarities

We have historic shopping basket data and are trying to predict future demand.
This works reasonably well for most items that are in a high number of shopping
baskets.

But the future demand of some items is currently predicted rather unsatisfactory. It
turns out, that a lot of those items are replacement items for other items.
These replacements items were sometimes only available for a short time instead
of the original item and are then again replaced by the original item.
Sometimes they replace the original item forever.

If a replacement item and original item are discovered and treated as one item,
the accuracy of the prediction improves immensly.

Is there a way to automatically discover (at least candidates) for
pairs of original and replacement parts?

**Bonus**: Sometimes there isn't a 1:1 relationship between original and
replacement item, but a 1:n relationship. Think replacing a 'Pizza Salami' with
a 'Plain Pizza' + 'Salami'.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem but could you please share some more details? What kind of data do you have (what variables: product names, date of introduction/absence of a product, classification of product, etc)?